# Contar quantidade de caracter específico em um intervalo

Tags: contador, google-sheets

Tenho um intervalo de dados parecido com esse:

[image]

Preciso contar quantos Vs e quantos Ds tem no intervalo.

Já tentei usando `SUMIF` e `COUNTIF`

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a seguinte fórmula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1:A7)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A7;"V";"")))
```

Onde:

- `A1:A7` = Faixa
- `"V"` = Caracter desejado

> Como funciona?
>
> - `LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A7;"V";""))` remove todas as ocorrências da letra "V" do texto e e conta o número de caracteres restantes
> - Calculando a diferença entre `LEN(A1:A7)` (texto original) e `LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A7;"V";""))` (texto sem os "V"s) é possível descobrir quantos Vs foram removidos do texto e assim saber quantas vezes o caracter aparece.
> - `SUMPRODUCT` soma os números da lista

[Fonte](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-specific-characters-in-a-range)

Comment: Muuuuito obrigado. Salvou! Haha